# Javascript: slider value won't change no matter what

Tags: javascript, slider, range

I want to **change the default value of a slider** on an external website, using Javascript through Tampermonkey. I would like that every time the page load, the default slider value would be 2, instead of 0 or 1 (the range is from 0 to 4).

Here is the HTML I see from Chrome Inspection:

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guCtB.png)

I have tried changing value by using Id (slider-subtask-1, slider-1..), for example:

```
document.getElementById("slider-1").value = "2";
```

or with querySelector:

```
document.querySelector("#slider-subtask-1").value = "2";
```

or by Name:

```
document.getElementsByName("trashiness.video.1")[0].value = "2";
```

or by Class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('evl-slider2-value-field')[0].setAttribute("value", "2");
```

or even this:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('evl-slider2-value-field')
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
  if (elms[i].getAttribute("value") === "1"){
   elms[i].setAttribute("value", "2");
  }
}
```

None has worked and I don't know what's the problem here. My other codes on the same website work well, except when it comes to change the slider's value. Note that I'm a total newbie in writing javascript and just try to "learn" it recently to automate some browser tasks. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The `input` is hidden. `slider-1` is the id of the div, not the input. They probably have custom slider implementation with several divs where the width of the slider is not governed by the input.

Comment: @adiga Thx, then the question is how can I find the correct slider ID/selector, or it's simply impossible for this case?